# Landscape RestAPI: How to gather process data?

Tags: landscape, apic

When I review a device within the Landscape UI, I can see its hardware inventory data as well as process inventory data; however, I only see a with_hardware parameter for the GetComputers method, which only provides hardware information.

Does anyone know how to gather the process inventory data for a device via the RestAPI